# A question on applying Residue Theorem to definite real integral

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

I came across [this question here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1807728/solution-ahlfors-4-5-3-3f) and even though it was not my own question it intrigued me so much that I tried to solve it:

> Using the Residue Theorem find
>
> $$\int_0^\infty \frac{x \sin(x)}{x^2+a^2} dx$$

But I got stuck and questions came up. Here are my thoughts:

First, I think the idea of applying the residue theorem would be to define a curve that is the boundary of one half of a disk centered at the origin. Then one computes the integral of $f$ around this half disk using the residue theorem. Finally, one uses this result by taking the limit of the radius towards infinity to find the integral in the question.

> Do I understand the idea of how to approach this problem correctly?

Here is how I tried to implement this:

First, we note that the poles are at $\pm ia$. So we want to choose the radius of the disk bigger than $a$. For example, $2a$ should do.

Then the curves that together form the contour (CCW) are:

$$ \gamma_1(t) = -2a + 2at, t \in [0,1]$$
and
$$ \gamma_2(t) = 2a e^{it}, t \in [0,\pi]$$

Then

$$ \oint_C f(z) dz = 2 \pi i \text{Res}_f (ia) = 2 \pi i \lim_{z \to ia} (z - ia) \frac{z \sin(z)}{z^2+a^2} = 2 \pi i \lim_{z \to ia}  \frac{z \sin(z)}{(z+ia)} =  \pi i { \sin(ia) }$$

Then

$$\begin{align} 
\int_{-2a}^{2a}f(z) dz &=  \oint_C f(z) dz - \oint_{\gamma_2} f(z) dz  \\
&=  \pi i { \sin(ia) } - \int_0^\pi {\gamma_2(t) \sin (\gamma_2(t)) \over \gamma_2^2(t) + a^2} 2ai e^{it} dt\\
&=\pi i { \sin(ia) } - \int_0^\pi {2a e^{it} \sin (2a e^{it}) \over 4a^2 e^{2it} + a^2} 2ai e^{it} dt\\
&=\pi i { \sin(ia) } - \int_0^\pi {2a e^{it} \sin (2a e^{it}) \over (2a e^{it} + ia)(2ae^{it} - ia)} 2ai e^{it} dt
\end{align}$$

And this is where I got stuck. I can't calculate $ \int_0^\pi {2a e^{it} \sin (2a e^{it}) \over (2a e^{it} + ia)(2ae^{it} - ia)} 2ai e^{it} dt$. This integral seems impossible to solve.

> Did I make a mistake in the approach? Or did I miscalculate somewhere?
>   Or is there a trick to solve integrals like this one?

Comment: Often, it can be useful to consider $e^{iz} $ instead of \sin(z) $, then take the imaginary part at the end.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. It is not clear to me yet how it will make the integral solvable since then I'd have $e^{i e^{it}}$ somewhere in the expression which seems even more difficult.

Answer (score 4):

There is a trick to circumvent the difficulty presented in the OP.  We note that $\sin(x)=\text{Im}(e^{ix})$.  Then, assuming that $a>0$, we evaluate the integral

$$\oint_{C_R} \frac{ze^{iz}}{z^2+a^2}\,dz=\int_{-R}^{R}\frac{xe^{ix}}{x^2+a^2}\,dx+\int_0^\pi \frac{Re^{it}e^{iRe^{it}}}{R^2e^{i2t}+a^2}\,iRe^{it}
\,dt \tag1$$

As $R\to \infty$, the second integral on the right-hand side of $(1)$ approaches $0$.  Therefore, find that

$$\begin{align}
2\pi i \text{Res}\left(\frac{ze^{iz}}{z^2+a^2},z=ia\right)&=2\pi i \frac{ia e^{-a}}{2ia}\\\\
&=i\pi e^{-a}\\\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{xe^{ix}}{x^2+a^2}\,dx \tag 2
\end{align}$$

Taking the imaginary part of $(2)$ and exploiting the evenness of the integrand reveals

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x\sin(x)}{x^2+a^2}\,dx=\frac{\pi e^{-a}}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

It has been too long since I have taken complex analysis.  But, it looks like you have evaluated the residual correctly.  The next step.

your function is an even function.

$\int_0^{\infty} f(z)dz = \frac12\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(z)dz$

If we make the contour the half circle above the x axis with radius R, + the real line from -R to R.

The semi-circle can be parameterized with z = Re^it

$\oint f(z) dz = \int_{-R}^{R} f(z)dz + \int_{0}^{\pi} f(Re^{it}) (iRe^{it}) dt$
$\pi sinh a =  \int_{-R}^{R} f(z)dz + \int_{0}^{\pi} f(Re^{it}) (iRe^{it}) dt$

What you hope is to be able to show that $\int_{0}^{\pi} f(Re^{it}) (iRe^{it}) dt$ goes to $0$ as R gets to be very large.

Now, if you didn't have a z in the numerator it would be simple.

but with what you have

$\int_{0}^{\pi} \dfrac {(R e^{it}) \sin (Re^{it}) (iRe^{it})}{R^2 e^{2it} + a^2} dt$

$\int_{0}^{\pi} \dfrac {\sin (Re^{it}) }{1 + \frac {a^2}{R^2} e^{-2it}} dt$
as R goes to infinity $\frac {a^2}{R^2} e^{-2it}$ goes to $0$
leaving.

$\int_{0}^{\pi} \sin (Re^{it})dt$

And I don't know what to do with that.

Answer (score 0):

I have a non-complex analysis solution using Feynmann Technique.

Let $\displaystyle I(a,b)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(ax)}{x(x^{2}+b)}dx$

So we have :-

$\displaystyle \frac{\partial I}{\partial a} = \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(ax)}{x^{2}+b} dx$

$\displaystyle \frac{\partial^{2}I}{\partial a^{2}} = -\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x\sin(ax)}{x^{2}+b}dx=
-\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(ax)}{x}dx + b\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(ax)}{x^{2}+b} dx
= -\frac{\pi}{2} + bI(a,b)$

Here I used the fact that $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(ax)}{x} = \frac{\pi}{2}$

So we have $\displaystyle (D^{2}-b)I = \frac{-\pi}{2}$  Here $\displaystyle D\equiv \frac{\partial}{\partial a}$

Solving this ODE in a we get

$\displaystyle I(a,b) =C_{1}e^{a\sqrt{b}} + C_{2}e^{-a\sqrt{b}} +\frac{\pi}{2b}$
We have $I(0,b) = 0$

So $\displaystyle C_{1}+C_{2} + \frac{\pi}{2b} = 0$

Also $\displaystyle \frac{\partial I}{\partial a} = \sqrt{b}(C_{1}e^{a\sqrt{b}} -C_{2}e^{-a\sqrt{b}})$

Also $\displaystyle \frac{\partial I}{\partial a}$ at $(0,b)$ = $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{x^{2}+b} = \frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{b}}$.

So we get $C_{1}=0$ and $C_{2} = \frac{-\pi}{2b}$

So $\displaystyle I(a,b) = \frac{-\pi}{2b}e^{-a\sqrt{b}} + \frac{\pi}{2b}$

$\displaystyle \frac{\partial I}{\partial a } = \frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{b}}e^{-a\sqrt{b}}$

$\displaystyle \frac{\partial^{2} I}{\partial a^{2}} = \frac{-\pi}{2}e^{-a\sqrt{b}}$

So as per the problem we need to replace $a=1$ in the above expression and multiply it with $-1$ to get our answer as :-$\displaystyle \frac{\pi}{2}e^{-\sqrt{b}}$. Also here $b=a^{2}$ . So our answer is $\displaystyle \frac{\pi}{2}e^{-a}$

Comment: I have fixed it @MarkViola . I missed the x in the denominator of $I(a,b)$

Comment: Consider justifying interchanging the integral and differential operators.

Comment: https://youtu.be/WP8JMVGuOD8 . Watch this @mark viola

Comment: The function $\frac{sin(ax)}{x(x^2+b)}$ is continuous for all x and all a and b>0. The partial derivative to it is continuous for all x and a and b>0. The improper integral of the function is uniformly convergent for all a by M-test . The improper integral of the partial derivative of the function is uniformly convergent for all a also by M-test . Hence justification of interchange of derivative and integral sign is valid as these form a suffocient set of conditions for us to do so.

Comment: Not quite.  For the second partial, the improper integral of the differentiated integrals is not UC for all $a$.  It is UC for all $a>\delta>0$.  Using this, the interchange is valid.

Comment: Ahh! bad mistake by me...sorry....I made a mistake while talking stuff out of the modulus. Sorry. Thanks @MarkViola